# How can I build a fool proof security system?

Tags: computability, rice-theorem

From what I understand, designing an IT security systems requires to build an algorithm D which can decide whether any program M is malicious or not.

That tasks looks very similar to me than deciding a non-trivial property of an arbitrary large set of programs. And as we know by Rice or diagonalization or many different methods, **this problem is undecidable**.

That means (if I am not wrong) that for some input D might run forever without sending a reply. **Obviously that's not acceptable for a security system. Let's assume for sake of simplicity, that I need a guaranteed YES or a NO.**

How can that be implemented in reality? And what are the consequences for the results?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the premise (that "designing an IT security system requires to build an algorithm D which can decide whether any program M is malicious or not") is simply false.

Comment: Maybe my statement was a bit too general. Would that fit the definition ? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_theorem_proving

Comment: Automated theorem proving is a whole field of study that tries to produce algorithms that derive mathematical facts. There has been a lot of work using it to prove properties of security protocols but only because it can solve problems that are too big for humans to solve, not because it can somehow solve impossible problems such as the halting problem. Regardless of what technique you might want to use, designing security systems doesn't involve the impossible task of deciding whether any given program is malicious.

Comment: Yeah that is exactly my point. As a antivirus for instance is meant to be able to scan an arbitrary large number or programs AND terminate everytime; what are the consequences of such a process. I guess that if a system is coherent (i.e. be able to identify when a program is indeed malicious) it would have to be incomplete (find false positives)?

Answer (score 1):

It is true that there is no general algorithm $D$ which can take as input *any* program $M$ and decide whether $M$ is malicious or not. Rice's theorem applies, here.

However, Rice's theorem does not imply that there is no $D$ that can do its job on a useful subset of programs $M$. This subset can not be the whole set of programs, according to Rice, but it could still be large enough to be useful in practice.

I'd say that most of the research in formal verification is about finding such a $D$ for specific cases. Usually the typical verifier $D$ outputs results meaning "I established that $M$ is malicious", "I established that $M$ is not malicious", or "my analysis was inconclusive, $M$ is too complex for me".

Essentially, we allow $D$ to throw the sponge, but hope that it won't.
We can't have a guaranteed YES or NO without also having, in infinitely many cases, the "inconclusive" result.

A naive technique to implement a $D$ could be to run $M$ for 1000 steps, and sees is $M$ does something bad. If it does, output "$M$ is malicious", otherwise output "inconclusive".

Static analyzers and model checkers (to mention two common approaches) only succeed on a subset of cases, but they can still be quite useful.

Comment: We can have a guaranteed "yes" or"no" if we restrict the set of programs enough. Even better, we can restrict the set of programs so the properties we want hold by construction, i.e. there are no "malicious" programs in the first place. Often this is done by designing the (often domain-specific) programming language appropriately, but there are several other approaches as well. There are several practical examples of this such an Dynamic Packet Filters and ADsafe.

Comment: You can trivially guarantee a yes or no.  guaranteeing a correct answer is not possible.